# VB2010 When I try to pull registry entry it comes up blank

Tags: vb.net, registry

Ok, I am trying to pull a Registry entry and it will not work, every time I try it pulls up an empty value. I tried running the individual exe as admin to double check the permissions. I created a batch file that performed an identical function and it worked fine, and I have also used an identical method to pull registry values on other parts of my script and can't seem to find the issue. The program runs fine and displays 0 errors.

Source Code:

```
' Check Auto Update settings
        Dim AUOptions_Value = My.Computer.Registry.GetValue("HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\WindowsUpdate\Auto Update", "AUOptions", Nothing)
        Dim AUOptions_level
        If AUOptions_Value = 4 Then
            AUOptions_level = "Auto Update Options set to: Install Updates Automatically."
            Display_AUOptions.ForeColor = Color.Green
        ElseIf AUOptions_Value = 3 Then
            AUOptions_level = "Download Updates but let me choose whether to install them."
            Display_AUOptions.ForeColor = Color.Blue
        ElseIf AUOptions_Value = 2 Then
            AUOptions_level = "Check for updates but let me choose whether to download them and install them."
            Display_AUOptions.ForeColor = Color.Blue
        ElseIf AUOptions_Value = 1 Then
            AUOptions_level = "Never check for updates."
            Display_AUOptions.ForeColor = Color.Red
        Else
            AUOptions_level = "Unable to detect settings"
            Display_AUOptions.ForeColor = Color.Red
        End If
        Display_AUOptions.Text = AUOptions_level
    End Sub
```

Registry Entry:

```
[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\WindowsUpdate\Auto Update]
"AUOptions"=dword:00000004
```

Comment: Are you building as 32bit on a 64bit os? If so you will actually read from `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Microsoft\Wind...` stick something in that key and check

Answer (score 0):

I suppose you are compiling you application for x86 and testing it on a 64bit OS.
In this case every read to the registry is automatically redirected by the OS to a different subtree of the registry. See MSDN on [32-bit and 64-bit Application Data in the Registry](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms724072%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

The OS change your registry path to this

```
"HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Microsoft\" & _
"Windows\CurrentVersion\WindowsUpdate\Auto Update"
```

Note how the OS change the subtree adding `Wow6432Node`. And here lies your problem, on 64 bit OS there is no `WindowsUpdate` subkey inside the `Wow6432Node`. (And that's right because these settings are managed by the 64bit OS)

To solve your issue try compiling your application for `AnyCPU` or `x64`

Comment: I have the stand alone version of Visual Basic 2010, how the heck do you set a project to AnyCPU? Everywhere I can find says i have to install the whole suit, which is, well stupid...

Also I knew the whole registry thing, i just didn't think that VB2010 was gunna start changing the values on me without at least some warning, this seems like a truely terrible idea, the default build option should leave the code untouched and build as is.

Comment: I don't know if this commands are available in the stand alone version os VB. Go to Compile menu, select Configuration Manager, Go to Platform combo and select AnyCPU. If not present select New and select AnyCPU as new platform. The go to the properties of your project and go to the Compile page, set the AnyCPU as platform if not already set.